# How to "pick" an element that is completely z-occluded by another element?

Tags: firefox-developer-tools

How can I use the inspector to visually select an element that is completely z-occluded by another element, preferably without first deleting or `display: none`ing the element that stands in the way?

Answer (score 0):

This is currently (as of Firefox 84) not possible without manually deleting them or setting `display: none` or `pointer-events: none` or something similar.

As that's something developers supposedly need quite often, I've filed a feature request to implement this feature: https://bugzil.la/1684699

Comment: To be entirely honest, I mostly need this to defeat hostile UI that sites like Quora use to "encourage" registering, but I also need it as a developer every once in a while.